# Multi-drop RS485 device control v1.0 - why is limit for "TIME_BETWEEN_MESSAGES "?

Tags: networking, timing, rs485

I am going to use Nick's rolling-master system library (http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11428) in my home project.

For first experiments and testing, I have:
- BAUD_RATE = 9600
- max adress = 2 (it means max 3 drops)
- 2 active drops with adress=0 and adress=1, 1 intentionally missing drop (simulation    of malfunction one of drops :-))
- TIME_BETWEEN_MESSAGES = 200000
- Packet length = 200 bytes
- Packet time = 208333 microseconds
- Timeout for no messages = 1633332 microseconds
- gap between messages = 200 ms (measured value by oscilloscope).
It work perfect.

I would like to increase the gap between the messages, but after I increased the constant "TIME_BETWEEN_MESSAGES"  from 200000 to 300000, then start bad communication  between the drops:
- TIME_BETWEEN_MESSAGES = 300000
- Packet length = 200 bytes
- Packet time = 208333 microseconds
- Timeout for no messages = 2033332 microseconds
- gap between messages = 2170 ms
Adress first started after reset (for example 1)  broadcasts, but nothing receives from other adress (for example 0), which started later.
Adress 0 receives all messages from adress 1 OK, but nothing transmits (subroutine "sendMessage ()" is never called).
After reseting of broacasting drop with adress  1, it works in reverse (addr 1 only receives, no broadcast, and addr 0 broadcasts).

Why is there limit for "TIME_BETWEEN_MESSAGES" value ? **How to increase gap between messages ?** For my purpose be enough gap 1 - 2 sec and so drops should have enough time for their own job.

Thanks for advice,
Vava
(Sorry for my English... :-)